# How I get the nth derivative of the function $y = e^x x^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm totally confused. Please anyone help me.

$y' = e^x x^2 + 2 e^xx$

$y''= e^x x^2 + 4 e^xx + 2e^x$

$y'''= e^x x^2 + 6 e^xx + 6 e^x$

next $y''''$ but I failed to get any pattern.

Comment: Can you find the first, second, third and fourth derivatives? Patterns will emerge. Can you spot them? If so, you know what you want to try to prove. If not, take a couple more derivatives and see if it's clearer.

Comment: $(uv)^{(n)}= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom {n} {k} u^{(k)}v^{(n-k)}$

Comment: You say you have the first four derivatives, and you fail to see a pattern in, say, the middle part:$$2e^xx\to 4e^xx\to6e^xx\to 8e^xx$$Really? There isn't a very obvious and simple pattern that jumps out to you here as a reasonable guess?

Comment: Thanks Its worked <3

Answer (score 13):

Consider the function:

$$f(\lambda,x) = \exp(\lambda x)$$

Then the function you want to differentiate n times w.r.t. x is $ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\lambda^2}$ at $\lambda = 1$. So, we want to evaluate:

$$ \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\lambda^2}$$

We can then interchange the order of differentiation to write this as:

$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda^2}\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^n}$$

We have:

$$\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x^n} = \lambda^n \exp(\lambda x)$$

differentiating twice w.r.t. $\lambda$ gives:

$$\left[n(n-1)\lambda^{n-2} + 2 n\lambda^{n-1} x + \lambda^n x^2\right]\exp(\lambda x)$$

Putting $\lambda = 1$ yields the result:

$$\left[n(n-1)+ 2 n x + x^2\right]\exp(x)$$

Comment: Great idea, I don't remember seeing it before :)

Comment: Easy Explanation ,Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

$y^{(1)}=\left(x^2+2x\right)e^x$

$y^{(2)}=\left(x^2+4x+2\right)e^x$

$y^{(3)}=\left(x^2+6x+6\right)e^x$

$y^{(4)}=\left(x^2+8x+12\right)e^x$

$y^{(5)}=\left(x^2+10x+20\right)e^x$

where $y^{n}$ is the nth derivative of the function

You see a pattern here where the $x^2$ is constant, the $x$ term increases by 2 every derivative, and the constant term is $(n-0.5)^2-0.25$.

With this pattern we can see that the nth derivative is $y^{n}=\left(x^2+2nx+((n-0.5)^2-0.25)\right)\cdot e^x$

Answer (score 4):

For the nth derivative of a function which can be written as product of 2 functions, we can use the formula
$(fg)^n= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom {n} {k} f^kg^{n-k}$

And it is quite easy to apply it as any nth derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ and differentiation of $x^2$ beyond 2nd derivative is just $0 $

So $(e^xx^2)^n=e^x(\binom {n} {0} x^2 +\binom {n} {1} 2x+ \binom {n} {2} 2)= e^{x}(x^{2}+2nx+n(n-1))
$

Answer (score 3):

$$y=e^xx^2$$
$$y'=e^xx^2+2e^xx=y+2xe^x$$
This leaves the result $2xe^x=y'-y$
$$y''=y'+2xe^x+2e^x=y'+(y'-y)+2e^x=2y'-y+2e^x$$
This leaves the result $2e^x=y''+y-2y'$
$$y'''=2y''-y'+2e^x=2y''-y+y''+y-2y'=3y''-2y'$$
The nth derivative for $n\geq4$ leaves:
$$y^{(n)}=3y^{((n-1))}-2y^{((n-2))}$$

Answer (score 2):

We need to find an expression to $\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}$.

Observe that you can use $\underline{\text{product rule}}$ and $\underline{\text{chain rule}}$ in each calculation of the derivative to $y$. Indeed

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x}(x^{2}+2x+(1-1)(1))$$
$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=e^{x}(x^{2}+2(2)x+(2-1)(2))$$
$$\frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}}=e^{x}(x^{2}+2(3)x+(3-1)(3))$$
$$\frac{d^{4}y}{dx^{4}}=e^{x}(x^{2}+2(4)x+(4-1)(4))$$
$$\frac{d^{5}y}{dx^{5}}=e^{x}(x^{2}+2(5)x+(5-1)(5))$$
so, by an inductive argument, we can see that
$$\boxed{\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}=e^{x}(x^{2}+2nx+(n-1)(n)), \quad n \in \mathbb{N}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Taylor series to do it. I don't say that it's the fastest and easiest method, but it's a possibility.

Let's define $f$ as
$$f(x):=x^2e^x$$
and let's fix a constant $a \in \mathbb{R}$. With this, we can define a new function $g$:
$$g(x):=f(x+a)=(x+a)^2e^{x+a}$$
With the chain rule, we can easily see that
$$g^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(a)$$
So if we can find the Maclaurin series of $g$, we are done. But it's easy, because:
\begin{align}
g(x)
&=(x+a)^2e^{x+a}\\
&=(x^2+2ax+a^2)e^ae^x \\
&=(x^2+2ax+a^2)e^a\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} \\
&=e^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}+2ae^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}+a^2e^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\\
&=e^a \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(n-2)!}+2ae^a \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(n-1)!}+a^2e^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\\
&=e^a \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}x^n\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+2ae^a \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^n\frac{n}{n!}+a^2e^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\\
&=e^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+2ae^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n\frac{n}{n!}+a^2e^a \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n\Bigg(e^a \frac{n(n-1)}{n!}+2ae^a\frac{n}{n!}+a^2e^a\frac{1}{n!} \Bigg)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\Bigg(e^a n(n-1)+2ae^an+a^2e^a \Bigg)\\
\end{align}
Which implies that
$$g^{(n)}(0)=e^a n(n-1)+2ae^an+a^2e^a=f^{(n)}(a)$$